# Create a Custom Shape Background that looks like a Coupon Item

Tags: java, android, xml

Want to create a layout for Redeem Items. Kindly suggest or help how can I accomplish this easily?

[Check this image for the idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yfv7.jpg)

[Dark Version of the item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxfbN.jpg)

Comment: Use card view and set corner radius for that card view.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a shape for a view.  A view is always a rectangle.  What you can do is make a view with a custom background with a non-rectangular shape and transparency in the area outside the shape, and use that as the background, which will make it appear as if it has a shape.

Comment: Can you give a try creating such a background or a layout?